# asp.net mvc5 ошибка в работе личного кабинета

Tags: asp.net

У каждого пользователя есть личный кабинет для просмотра своих данных. Но при входе на сервис очередного клиента, все уже находящиеся на сервисе получают уже не свои данные, а последнего вошедшего. В запросе к Б.Д. указан ID клиента, но он автоматически меняется на ID вновь вошедшего. 
Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем может быть причина.

Comment: Покажите ваш код, мы же без кода как догадаемся в чём проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> но он автоматически меняется на ID вновь вошедшего ...  в чем может
>   быть причина.

`<телепатия>`

Вы используете для "ID клиента" статическое поле класса, или оно содержится в контейнере, являющимся статическим полем класса.

Не используйте `static` для этой цели.

`</телепатия>`

Comment: спасибо, Igor. В яблочко. К сожалению, у меня еще нет прав, чтобы поднять рейтинг вашего ответа.

Comment: @Tatnikol Рад, что смог помочь. Вы можете отметить этот ответ как принятый, щелкнув по знакоу "галочка" слева. Успехов.